# Change colors on based on expression

Tags: reporting-services, colors, switch-statement, iif

I have percentage calculated field and it has to have different color based on values:

- where <70% is red
- 70% to 79.9% is Yellow
- 80%+ is green

I tried:

```vb
=Switch((Sum(Fields!TotalQtySUM.Value, "DataSet1")/Sum(Fields!REG_HOURS.Value, "DataSet1")) < 0.7, "Red" ,
    (Sum(Fields!TotalQtySUM.Value, "DataSet1")/Sum(Fields!REG_HOURS.Value, "DataSet1")) < 0.8, "Black",
    (Sum(Fields!TotalQtySUM.Value, "DataSet1")/Sum(Fields!REG_HOURS.Value, "DataSet1")) >= 1, "Green")
```

And:

```vb
=IIF((Sum(Fields!TotalQtySUM.Value, "DataSet1")/Sum(Fields!REG_HOURS.Value, "DataSet1")) < 0.7, "Red" ,"Green")
```

They either all red or change the colors randomly without following any rules
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your first operator is overriding your other operator: '< 0.7' is true for the color before '< 0.8'.  Try to reverse the first two criteria and that may fix your issue.  I ran into something similar to this and I believe this is how I fixed it.  Also you don't need to do Sum(Fields!(Field).Value, "(Dataset)"),  You can just do this: "Sum(Fields!(Field).Value)".

The second criteria you gave though I would test the value you are getting by itself.  It seems the second set may be valid but the expression may not be what you are expecting.
Also I would just add a 'computed' field to my dataset instead of doing it in an expression.  This may be faster than the expression evaluation in the end.  The more expressions you use in SSRS the slower the report becomes.  I know when an expression does not work for setting a property I usually go through the parts piece by piece.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Although how do you add calculations to the dataset? I don’t think I am familiar with that?

Comment: Right Click your dataset and hit 'Add Computed Column' I believe.  Or you can just do it in the dataset in the TSQL directly if you are using a Select statement query.  Remember to mark you answer completed if you got everything you needed and happy SSRS coding.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to calculate sum on last four coumns in my matrix using this calculated dataset?

Comment: You could in essence do the same expression you are essentially doing here: =Sum(Fields!TotalQtySUM.Value)/Sum(Fields!REG_HOURS.Value) by selecting the dataset and right clicking and chooing 'Add Calculated Field'.  You can then use this field to make determinations.  This would break up your code a little bit to potentially make it more re usable.  Up to you though of course :)